# Yii2 Strange Post Parameters After File Download

Tags: php, parameters, download, yii2

I have an ActiveForm with two submit buttons.  One of the buttons processes the form and displays the results with a page refresh, and the other processes the form and downloads a CSV file of the results.  Both buttons work independently, but if I download the CSV file, and then click on the web refresh button, it downloads the CSV file instead.  I will try to include relevant code below:

View:

```
// This is inside an ActiveForm with a bunch of other fields
<?= Html::submitButton('Process', ['class' => 'btn btn-success', 'value'=>'process', 'name'=>'submit-type']) ?>
<?= Html::submitButton('Download', ['class' => 'btn btn-success', 'value'=>'exportCSV', 'name'=>'submit-type']) ?>
```

Controller:

```
// ... do a bunch of processing up here
$submitType = Yii::$app->request->post('submit-type');
if (isset($submitType) && $submitType == "exportCSV")
{
    $this->outputCSV($columnNames);
    die;
}
$this->render('index', ...);
```

Comment: Nothing strange and this has nothing to do with yii2...

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear.  I click on the Download button, and it works.  The file downloads without refreshing the page.  If I click on the Process button after that, it downloads the file again rather than processing.  The submit-type should be set to process when I click on that, even if it's after clicking export beforehand, right?

Comment: You use a different view for output the csv? anyway try with `unset($_POST['submit-type'])` before `die`, but I don't think using `die` is a good practice here.